# Product sliders in list view

Tags: product, slider

When trying to find a slider to display my products on frontpage i found a lot out there. 
But no of them could make a slider in list view.

What I am looking for is something like this 
[image]

I want to make 3 produkt with a width of 100%. then slide to se 3 new.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [owl carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/responsive.html) slider

Add below code in homepage

```
{{block type="core/template" name="homepage-slide" template="yourtemplate/yourtemplate.phtml"}}
```

Your below code to template **yourtemplate/yourtemplate.phtml**:

```
  <div id="owl-demo">
    <?php i=1; foreach($collection as $child){ ?>
      <?php if($i == 0 || $i%3 == 0) { ?>
        <div class="item">
          <ul> 
      <?php } ?>
            <li>Product code here</li>               
      <?php $i++; if($i%3 == 0) { ?>
           </ul>
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
   <?php  } ?>    
    </div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});
```

It helpful to you

Comment: Nice! How do i get the block on frontpage to post 6 product, with this around every third li? :O

Comment: Updated code check it.

Comment: Fantastik! Quick and easy!

Comment: oh! it seams like i cant get it to slide properply. Is there some introduktion to the owl slider? :)

Comment: Refer it http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/started-welcome.html